# Delphi 10.1 Berlin Fast Report - TfrxDesigner Component Missing

Tags: delphi, fastreport, delphi-10.1-berlin

I could not find `TfrxDesigner` Component in my Tool Palette. What should I do? Im using `Embarcadero® RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin Version 24.0.22858.6822`.

Comment: Did you install the full version of FastReport?

Comment: @UweRaabe -> I think it is pre-installed together during RAD Studio installation. Am I wrong?

Comment: The version that comes with RAD Studio is not the full version. The designer is only available with the full version which has to be purchased separately.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the menu option : Component -> Install Packages, and look for the FastReport package. If it's unchecked, you just need to check it, but if it is not there, you would need to reinstall it.

Comment: FastReport 5.0 Components, FastReport 5.0 DB Components and FastReport 5.0 Exports package is there and is checked. Why does  TfrxDesigner is missing?

Comment: Try loading an older project with a frxDesigner in it. Does it show it ?.

Comment: I have never used frxDesigner before.

Comment: Looks like you are using the Embarcadero version of FastReport embedded on Delphi. This version doesn't have the designer available, you need to buy a commercial version of FastReport to use it.

Answer (score 0):

1.Make sure that you are using design mode of the form when searching for component 
2.Make sure that you added "...\Fast Report\Source" path to library path in options